# I am adding a button to elements as they are generated in html and than giving them an onclick handler but getting errors

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a project in which I am using the GIPHY api to generate gifs based off of a keyword given by the user. I am able to add the buttons to my results.

I am also adding an onclick event to each of the image results by doing the following code:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        let result = results[i];

        //11
        let smallURL = result.images.fixed_width_downsampled.url;
        if (!smallURL) smallURL = "IMages/no-image-found.png";

        //12
        let url = result.url;
        //13
        let line = `<div class = 'result'><img src ='${smallURL}' title = '${result.id}' />`;
        line += `<span><a target='_blank' href = '${url}'>View on Giphy</a> <p>Rating: ${result.rating.toUpperCase()}</p><button type="button" class="favorite"">Favorite GIF</button></span></div>`;

        //15
        bigString += line;
    }

    //16
    document.querySelector("#content").innerHTML = bigString;
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".favorite");
    for(let k = 0; k < buttons.length; k++){
        buttons[k].onclick = favoriteButtonClicked;
    }
```

`

I am able to click the button once to get my function favoriteButtonClicked to run. But when I click a second button it either doesn't run or runs on the window instead. This is what my function looks like, if anyone could help that would be great.

```js
function favoriteButtonClicked() {
    console.log("Fav");
    let list = this.parentElement.parentElement;
    this.innerHTML = "Unfavorite";
    let fav  = "";
    fav += `<img src="${list.childNodes[0].src}" title = "${list.childNodes[0].title}"/>`;
    favorite_gifs.push(fav);
    document.querySelector("#content").innerHTML += fav;
}
```

Comment: Try this `buttons[k].onclick = () => {favoriteButtonClicked()};`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured it out, what the issue was was at the on of my favButtonsClicked method when I changed the innerHTML all the onclick events were being removed. So I changed things up and now it works. Thank you!

Comment: If you found a solution, make sure to include it and mark the relevant answer as accepted, that way people can see that you resolved it and those who have the same issue can see how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're trying to actually **set** the `onclick` attribute you need to actually `setAttribute` but I'd suggest actually just adding direct event listeners so you could also clear them when / if not needed. Here's a quick PoC to get you started. Cheers!

```js
const btns = document.querySelectorAll('.fav');

for(var i = 0, x = btns.length; i < x; i++) {
 btns[i].addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}

function clickHandler(event) {
 alert(`Congrats, you clicked : ${event.target.id.toUpperCase()}`);
}
```

```html
<button class="fav" id="button1">Button 1</button>
<button class="fav" id="button2">Button 2</button>
<button class="fav" id="button3">Button 3</button>
<button class="fav" id="button4">Button 4</button>
```

Comment: I eventually figured it out, what the issue was was at the on of my favButtonsClicked method when I changed the innerHTML all the onclick events were being removed. So I changed things up and now it works. Thank you!